# AMS article section headings in sans-serif

Tags: fonts, sectioning, amsart

I want to produce an AMS article document using only a sans-serif font. The following almost achieves this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

...
```

However, section headings are still typeset in roman. How can I get also the section headings in the standard sans-serif font?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that the class does

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
```

and the default font set does not have small caps sans serif.
If you want sans serif you either need to change fonts or disable small caps

```
 \let\scshape\relax
```

is a blunt instrument, but probably effective in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I would be happy with this as long as I could make the section headings a bit bigger.

Comment: well copy the definition I show and change \normalfont to \large or \Huge or whatever (and same for the other headings) you will find the definitions in amsart.cls